# Is it mandatory to activate virtual environment before deploying django apps on heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

I am trying to deploy a django website project with 3 apps on heroku. In the heroku website it is mentioned to activate virtual environment before deploying apps. But the venv file is taking a lot of space (actually it is taking the 50% of the space of my project) and deploying it is taking a lot of time. I hope for a nice answer. :)

Comment: Have you tried without? How many dependencies does your project have?

Comment: I have 4 dependencies

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Activating a virtualenv has no effect on deployment time, because the virtualenv is not deployed, just your code is.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use a virtualenv in your local development is up to you, but in either case you'll have to specify a requirements.txt file so Heroku knows what Python packages/dependencies to install.

Creating a minimal requirements.txt is very easy using a virtualenv, as outlined in Heroku's [tutorial for Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration).

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```